# Using stop words with WhitespaceAnalyzer

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Lucene's StandardAnalyzer removes dots from string/acronyms when indexing it.
I want Lucene to retain dots and hence I'm using WhitespaceAnalyzer  class.

I can give my list of stop words to StandardAnalyzer...but how do i give it to  WhitespaceAnalyzer?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own analyzer by extending WhiteSpaceAnalyzer and override [tokenStream](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html#tokenStream(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader)) method as follows.

```
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    TokenStream result = super.tokenStream(fieldName, reader);
    result = new StopFilter(result, stopSet);
    return result;
}
```

Here the stopSet is the Set of stop words, which you could get by adding a constructor to your analyzer which accepts a list of stop words.

You may also wish to override reusableTokenStream() method in similar fashion if you plan to reuse the TokenStream.

Comment: could you please have a loot at my answer and comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899542/problem-using-same-instance-of-indexsearcher-for-multiple-requests/1014501#1014501

Comment: @Shashikant Kore - Any inputs for question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554850/solrj-query-get-the-most-relevant-record-first